# Abrir modal con id php y borrar registro

Tags: php, jquery, modal

Intento borrar registros pero al pulsar el botón del registro se me borra siempre el último registro de la BBDD. En el enlace del bóton está bien el id, pero en el modal me llega siempre el id del último registro.
El botón que abre el modal:

```
<a type="button" href="#"
   class="fa fa-trash-o btn btn-danger deleteUser" 
   data-toggle="modal" 
   data-target="#deleteModal" 
   data-name="<?php echo h(u($group->name)); ?>" 
   data-id="<?php echo h(u($group->id)); ?>">  Borrar <?php echo h(u($group->id)); ?></a>



El modal es este:

        <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
            <div class="modal-dialog" role="user">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <h5 class="modal-title" id="deleteModalLabel">Borrar Usuario <?php echo h(u($admin->id)); ?></h5>
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                            <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                        </button>
                    </div>

                    <div class="modal-body">
                        <p>Estas seguro de que quieres borrar el usuario <span style="color: #d34;"><?php echo h($admin->username); ?></span> ?</p>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">                        
                  <div id="operations">
                        <button type="submit" class="fa fa-trash btn btn-danger deleteUserConfirm"> Borrar</button>
                        <button type="button" class="fa fa-trash btn btn-warning" data-dismiss="modal"> Ignorar</button>
                    </div>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Y el script es este:

```
    <script>
        $('#deleteModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (e) {
            var id = $(e.relatedTarget).data('id');
            console.log(id);
            $(e.currentTarget).find('input[name="id"]').val(id);
        });
</script>
```

En php recojo el id luego llamo a la función de borrar que esta dentro de una clase:

```
$id = $_GET['id'];
$admin = Admin::find_by_id($id);
if (is_post_request()) {
    $result = $admin->delete();
    $session->message('El documento ha sido borrado correctamente.');
    redirect_to(url_for('/views/staff/users/index_users.php'));
}
```

He probado muchas cosas y con todo el mismo resultado, me borra el últmo registro.

Gracias!

Comment: ¿Cuál es el código que usas para borrar los registros? Puedes [edit] la pregunta para ponerlo. Gracias.

Comment: en el modal le estas pasando un id por url, si el modal se imprime al final de la lista de registros será el último, si hay un modal por cada registro el "#deleteModal" es impredecible, también hay una diferencia entre el method post del form y el `$id = $_GET['id'];` del php

Comment: He borrado el form que había en el modal. Solo he dejado el botón de enviar. He simplificado el botón ` <a type="button" href="#"
                                       class="fa fa-trash-o btn btn-danger deleteUser" 
                                       data-toggle="modal" 
                                       data-target="#deleteModal" 
                                       data-name="<?php echo h(u($group->name)); ?>" 
                                       data-id="<?php echo h(u($group->id)); ?>">  Borrar <?php echo h(u($group->id)); ?></a>`.

Comment: Creo que te he entendido ahora @aloMalbarez. Es porque lanzo el modal de dentro de un foreach y por esto me abre siempre el último.